# Do not create XElement when value is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have the below code which is working, however; I want to omit XElements that have no value and have been unable to figure this out. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
        {

            result.Add(new XElement(new XElement("action",
                                             new XElement("actionType", row["actionType"].ToString()),
                                             new XElement("originalUnits", row["originalUnits"].ToString()),
                                             new XElement("adjustedUnits", row["adjustedUnits"].ToString()),
                                             new XElement("adjustmentPercentage", row["adjustmentPercentage"].ToString()),
                                             new XElement("userMessageCode", row["userMessageCode"].ToString()),
                                             new XElement("review", row["review"].ToString())


                                             )));


        }
```

**UPDATE:**

The below code compiles but the empty elements are still present.

```
       result.Add(new XElement(new XElement("action",
                                         new XElement("actionType", row["actionType"].ToString()),
                                         row["originalUnits"].ToString() != null ? new XElement("originalUnits", row["originalUnits"].ToString()) : null,
                                         row["adjustedUnits"].ToString() != null ? new XElement("adjustedUnits", row["adjustedUnits"].ToString()) : null,
                                         new XElement("adjustmentPercentage", row["adjustmentPercentage"].ToString()),
                                         new XElement("userMessageCode", row["userMessageCode"].ToString()),
                                         new XElement("review", row["review"].ToString())


                                         )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the value with [`DBNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `null` For example,

```
result.Add(new XElement(new XElement("action",
                                         new XElement("actionType", row["actionType"].ToString()),
                                         row["originalUnits"] != DBNull.Value ? new XElement("originalUnits", row["originalUnits"].ToString()) : null,
                                         row["adjustedUnits"] != DBNull.Value ? new XElement("adjustedUnits", row["adjustedUnits"].ToString()) : null,
                                         new XElement("adjustmentPercentage", row["adjustmentPercentage"].ToString()))));
```

`DBNull` represents a nonexistent value returned from the database. This is different from `null`

> Do not confuse the notion of null in an object-oriented programming language with a DBNull object. In an object-oriented programming language, null means the absence of a reference to an object. DBNull represents an uninitialized variant or nonexistent database column.

Comment: Thank you. That was it.